# Vaadin: how do I use Navigator from a View?

Tags: grails, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm looking at Vaadin plugin in Grails at the moment and this is what I'm trying to implement:

I have an `UI` class and two `View` classes

The UI code has a navigator in it:

```
class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this)

        navigator.addView(MainView.NAME, new MainView())

        navigator.addView(CountView.NAME, CountView.class)

    }
}
```

In the MainView there is a `Button` and I want the user to be redirected to `CountView` after the button is clicked. I added the `Button.ClickListener()`, but I can't get hold of the `Navigator` instance in the `View` to navigate to the desired page.

I'd be grateful if you could provide me an example of this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can say

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("foobar");
```

or

```
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo("foobar");
```